# Compilation failure: [...] cannot access javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas, class file for javax.media.opengl.awt.glcanvas not found

Tags: java, user-interface, opengl, jogl, glcanvas

I get a compilation failure when trying to compile code that uses WorldWind for dependencies. Here is a screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72hYg.png)

I tried downgrading JOGL, but that did not work. I cannot directly change the format to what works now because the file it is in is an external JAR file that I imported (NASA WorldWind)

Thanks

Comment: The version of NASA Worldwind you use relies on a very old version of JOGL and you probably tried to compile your source code against a more recent version of JOGL in which javax.media no longer exists for legal reasons. Either use the same old version of JOGL than NASA Worldwind or modify and recompile NASA Worldwind with the most recent version of JOGL. By the way, rather ask JOGL specific questions on the official JogAmp forum.

Comment: @gouessej I used the JOGL that was included with WorldWind, though?

Comment: Then use the right package for GLCanvas: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/awt/GLCanvas.html

Comment: @gouessej I figured it out. It's referencing javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas rather than javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas, but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: NASA Worldwind still uses an obsolete version of JOGL then :( Which version of NASA Worldwind do you use?